# How do I get a set of random numbers where a single number only appears once?

Tags: random, rust

For example, in a Tetris game, the game randomizes the pieces as if they were picked from a bag.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what the use-case is e.g. with the case of tetris you can just create a sequence of pieces, shuffle() it, and pop values until the sequence is empty. Alternatively, `rand::seq::index::sample` will take a length and an amount and will return `amount` distinct shuffled values between `0` and `length`.

Answer (score 4):

Randomizing, as you describe it, is done by *shuffling* sets.

The [rand](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/) crate implements this shuffling (and has an example).

Here's printing numbers from 1 to 10 without repetition, in a random order:

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut nums: Vec<i32> = (1..=10).collect();
    nums.shuffle(&mut rng);
    for num in nums {
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dddacab2b29335b2fc15aa03a0467d9a)